# More Navigation Controller for iPad in ios 9 giving a white space

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

More Navigation Controller for iPad in ios 9 giving a white space at the right side. I have tried to findout the tableview frame, but the tableview and tableview cell fit exactly with the same width of iPad. But the tableviewcell contentView width is less and not completely fitting.Anyone have a tweak to this? [image]

Comment: check once your constraints

Comment: There is no constraints explicitly added. When the tab items are more, by default this More tab and the tableview appeared.

Comment: set background color (for ex, green) for table and check it's position

Comment: I tried to set background color for tableview and tableview cell, both have perfect width. But when I tried for cell contentView, the width is just upto the arrow only. Anyway as of now I have done an indirect fix by adding a custom subview to the cell. But couldn't find why this is happening. Till ios 8, it is working fine.